# Calculate timetable / Remaining time (Java)

Tags: java, date, time

I am trying to calculate remaining time for bus timetable. So I stored all list of tables in ArrayList, and I want to calculate the remaining time only just for one timetable at a time. For example, assume the list has 8:00 and 8:15, and the current time is 7:55. What I want is that calculate the remaining time with 8:00 not 8:15, and also if the current time is 8:01, the calculation should be happening with 8:15 not 8:00. If you guys help me with that (any links or sample methods), that would be fantastic.

Comment: I can calculate the time differences between two dates, but it's only happening with the first one (even though the time difference is minus). I have no idea how to sort the list based on the current time.

Comment: Sort the `List`, use a `BinarySearch` to find a suitable (closes) match...

Answer (score 1):

A lot comes down to how you are storing your time information, for example, if you are using something like `Date` or `LocalTime`, you can simply sort the `List` of times and use `Collections.binarySearch` to find a suitable time...

```
List<LocalTime> times = new ArrayList<>(25);
times.add(LocalTime.of(9, 0));
times.add(LocalTime.of(8, 45));
times.add(LocalTime.of(8, 30));
times.add(LocalTime.of(8, 15));
times.add(LocalTime.of(8, 0));
times.add(LocalTime.of(7, 45));
times.add(LocalTime.of(7, 30));
times.add(LocalTime.of(7, 15));
times.add(LocalTime.of(7, 0));

int result = Collections.binarySearch(times, LocalTime.of(7, 55), new Comparator<LocalTime>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(LocalTime o1, LocalTime o2) {

        LocalTime startRange = o1.minusMinutes(15);
        LocalTime endRange = o1;

        if ((o2.equals(o1) || startRange.isBefore(o2)) && (o2.equals(o1) || o2.isBefore(o1))) {
            return 0;
        } 
        return o1.compareTo(o2);
    }
});

if (result >= 0) {
    System.out.println(times.get(result));
}
```

Which outputs `08:00`

Now,

```
if ((o2.equals(o1) || startRange.isBefore(o2)) && (o2.equals(o1) || o2.isBefore(o1))) {
```

Is matching an exact period (7:45-8:00 inclusive, for example), this might not be what you want (so it's 8:00, you've probably missed the bus ;)) so you might be able to use something like

```
if (startRange.isBefore(o2) && o2.isBefore(o1)) {
```

which will match 7:46-7:59 inclusive, for example or combinations based on your needs...

Comment: @user2068889 It was fun ;)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the list is sorted, you can loop through the list and return the first element which the difference is positive.

Pseudocode:

```
for each time in timetable:
    difference = time - current_time
    if difference > 0: return difference
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I have an idea how to start this thing :)